# Why does some characters change?

Tags: c, string

I'm programming with `C language` in CodeBlocks with **GNU GCC** compiler.I was writing a function to create some `Link List` consisting token as nodes.for example, for the below text file:

```
main ( )
{
int a ;
int b ;
}
```

the link list of tokens would be

`main -> ( -> ) -> { -> int -> a -> ; -> int -> b -> ; -> }`

for which the delimiter is the `space` character.
Then i decided to make some other link list called `line`. Each line consisting successive tokens separated by space finished by `;` character. For example , at the same text file with the relevant tokens the lines would be:

`main ( ) { int a ; -> int b ;-> }`

you see my code below:

```
//including the related Header files
typedef struct token {
    char *tok;
    struct token *next;
    int tp;
} token;


typedef struct line {
    char *ls;
    struct line *next;
    int parent;
} line;

token *start;
line *lstart;

void addline (line * a);
void showline (void);
void setline (void);

int main (void ) {

    int i = 0;

    // the next 4 lines allocates some space for start(pointer of type token)
    // and lstart(pointer of type line) as the first node in the link
    // list.The first meaningful data of each type are stored in the nodes
    // after the start and lstart node


    start = (token *) malloc (sizeof (token));
    start->next = NULL;

    lstart = (line *) malloc (sizeof (line));
    lstart->next = NULL;

    FILE *p;

    p = fopen ("sample.txt", "r+");
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf ("Can Not Open File");
        exit (1);
    }
    //calling some fnuction for making link list of tokens from the text
    //file

    setline ();
    showline ();

    return 0;

}

// the relevant add functions which adds a new token or 
// link list at the end of the list
void showline ()
{
    line *p;
    p = lstart->next;
    while (p != NULL) {
        printf ("%s\n", p->ls);
        p = p->next;
    }
}

void setline (void)
{
    int parent;
    token *p;
    p = start->next;

    line *q;

    q = (line *) malloc (sizeof (line));

    q->ls = NULL;

    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p == NULL) {
            break;
        }

        q->ls = strdup (p->tok);
        strcat (q->ls, " ");
        p = p->next;

        while ((p != NULL)) {
            if (strcmp (p->tok, ";") == 0) {
                strcat (q->ls, "; ");
                p = p->next;
                break;
            }
            strcat (q->ls, p->tok);
            strcat (q->ls, " ");
            p = p->next;
        }

        printf ("%s\n", q->ls);
        addline (q);
        q->ls = NULL;
    }
}
```

and I stored some data in the text file "sample.txt" :

```
#include <something.h> 
int a , b ;
main ( )
{
int a ;
int b ;
}
```

I expected lines will be made correctly but something strange happened when I called `showline()` function (This function is used and can be seen in the `main` ):In some lines there was some strange characters.For example the `ls` of the second `line` node was expected to be `int b ;` But what Really happened was `înt b ;` in which the usual `i` character turned into `î`(a strange character) .Which mistake did i make when working with strings?

Comment: Could you please add the addline definition also in the snippet.

Comment: `q=(line *)malloc(sizeof(line));`

Type casting is not required here (if you are using C compiler) as malloc return `void*` which will me automagically type-casted.

Comment: @D.7: Thanks but this was not my major problem

Answer (score 3):

*One* of the problematic places:

```
q->ls=strdup(p->tok);
strcat(q->ls," ");
```

The `strdup` function allocates enough space for `p->tok` *only*, there's no space to append anything after the copies string. So calling `strcat` will of course write out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*.

If you want to append more characters, you need to allocate yourself (using `malloc` or `calloc`) with the size you need, and then manually copy the initial string.

Comment: for example, if I use this: `q->ls=(char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));` knowing there will be less than 100 characters in each line then the problem would be fixed?

Comment: I allocated space for `q->ls` . And I changed `strdup` line into:`strcpy(q->ls,p->tok) `.But I got Runtime Error!